# Getting infinite loop and not able to fetch data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, axios

This the code that is responsible for getting Data and updating the list:

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const initialState = {
    log: []
}

let page = 1;

const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'cart',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
        fetching: (state, payload) => {
            state.log = axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/fetch/?${page = payload.payload}`)
            // console.log(state)
        }
    }
})

export const {fetching} = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

And this is the Home Page:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {fetching} from "../features/cardSlice";
import Cards from "./Cards";

export default function HomePage(){



    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const {itemsList} = useSelector((store) => store.card)
    console.log(itemsList)
    const {pageNumber} = useSelector((store) => store.page);

    useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(fetching(1));   **// This is where i call dispatch to update the state and get the data**
    })

    function cardMapper(items) {
        return(
            <Cards
                name = {items.name}
                key = {items.id}
                cuisine={items.cuisine}
                address={items.address}
            />
        )
    }

    return(
        <div>
            {/*{itemsList.map(cardMapper)}*/}
        </div>
    )
}
```

When i run this on localhost i am not able to get data, the console.log(itemList) is showing undefined and also the dispatch(fetching(1)) is called infinite times.

> Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I am not able to understand why i'm getting an infinite loop and also why am i not getting the data.

Comment: I'd start with adding an empty array as `useEffect` reference to make sure the hook fires only on the initial component render which is probably what you need (`useEffect(()=>{         dispatch(fetching(1)); }, [] )`)

Comment: Thank you @WiktorZychla that solved the infinite loop issue but am i doing some mistake with my axios.get() as i'm still not able to fetch the data.

Comment: you should `await`

Comment: @Moeinmoeinnia i tried but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code. To prevent infinite loop in using useEffect you should put [] as dependency
And for the useSelector,the variable should not enclosed by {}.
see the modified code below.
As I see, it should be **cart** not **card**

Try this code instead

```
export default function HomePage(){

        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const itemsList = useSelector((store) => store.cart)
        console.log(itemsList)
        const {pageNumber} = useSelector((store) => store.page);
    
        useEffect(()=>{
            dispatch(fetching(1));   **// This is where i call dispatch to update the state and get the data**
        },[])
    
        function cardMapper(items) {
            return(
                <Cards
                    name = {items.name}
                    key = {items.id}
                    cuisine={items.cuisine}
                    address={items.address}
                />
            )
        }
    
        return(
            <div>
                {/*{itemsList.map(cardMapper)}*/}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

also in reducer
add a return

```
 fetching: async (state, payload) => {
          const newState = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/fetch/?${page = payload.payload}`)
          return newState; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **You need added dependencies as an empty array.** To remove the yellow
> squiggly line you need to add dispatch inside that dependencies array.
> however, react to ensure that dispatch dependencies never change and
> that you are not responsible for re-render your component.

```
useEffect(()=>{
 dispatch(fetching(1))
},[dispatch])
```

Answer (score 0):

// this should end the infinite loop
useEffect(()=>{
dispatch(fetching(1));   **// This is where i call dispatch to update the state and get the data**
}, [ ])